# Recommended way to maintain stored procedures, user defined functions, indexes, etc. in source control and for CI/CD

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

For our stored procedures, we were using an approach that was working rather well during CD which was making use of the javascript v2 SDK to call `container.storedProcedures.upsert`. Upsert has now been removed from the API on v3 as it's not supported on non-partitioned collections (which are the only ones you'll be able to create from now on).

I supposed that the v3 SDK would have a way to at least delete and re-create these objects, but for what I can see it only allows creation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/cosmos/storedprocedures?view=azure-node-latest
We followed a similar approach for maintaing the index definitions updated and this is the main reason we now need to migrate to the v3 SDK as otherwise updating some kind of indexes fail through v2.

Given that what we want (if possible) is to be able to maintain all of these objects in soure control and automatically deploy them during CD, what would be the recommended way to do this?

(Meanwhile I'm exploring using these powershell commands for it: https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB but attempting to create a UDF through them caused a very bizzarre outcome in which Azure Portal stopped showing me *any* UDF on the collection until I removed the one I had created using `New-CosmosDbUserDefinedFunction`)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options today and your choices will get better here over the next couple of months.

Cosmos now has support for creating stored procedures, triggers and UDFs using ARM Templates. The second sample on this page has an ARM template that shows this. [Cosmos DB ARM Template Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/resource-manager-samples). This PS tool you are using is not officially supported so you'll need to file an issue there for any questions. We will be releasing PS Cmdlets to create stored procedures, triggers and UDF's but there is no ETA to share at this time.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll look into this and also wait to check on those Cmdlets once available.

Comment: btw, I'll be releasing Azure Management Library samples here in the next week or two. This is another option where you can use C# code to provision and manage all of your Cosmos DB resources and keep it in version control. The GitHub repo is here. Keep an eye on it over the next week or two. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-management-net Thanks.

Comment: Great!, looking forward to it! Thanks

Comment: Are Azure Management Libraries idempotent ?